# Orderby and Linq

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

How can i add orderby to this:

```
return (from m in response["holder"].Children()
                orderby m["name"]
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = m["name"].ToString(),
                    Value = m["name"].ToString()
                }).ToList();
```

The problem is that the json returned in the response variable has a list of names, all of them have an uppercase first letter apart from one so they all get ordered fine except the one with the lower case which gets stuck at the bottom of the SelectListItem list.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance..

EDIT:

Additional info - i am using JSON.NET to parse the json response. And the response variable is a JObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to normalize the data during your `orderby`.  In my example I've chosen to use the [`ToUpperInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx) method:

```
return (from m in response["holder"].Children()
        orderby m["name"].ToUpperInvariant()
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = m["name"].ToString(),
            Value = m["name"].ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

I'm also assuming that `m["name"]` is already a `String` object. If it's not, change the line to:

```
orderby m["name"].ToString().ToUpperInvariant()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - this worked. A bunch of the standard ordering that i tried didnt work as the response is a JObject from JSON.NEt. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
return (from m in response["holder"].Children()
                orderby m["name"].ToString().ToLower()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = m["name"].ToString(),
                    Value = m["name"].ToString()
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `OrderBy` method in the *method syntax*, you can specifiy a `StringComparer`. Passing a `StringComparer` that ignores casing solves your issue:

```
response["holder"]
  .Children()
  .OrderBy(m => m["name"], StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response["holder"]
  .Children()
  .OrderBy(m => m["name"] as String, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
  .Select(m => new SelectedListItem 
                   {
                       Text = m["name"].ToString(),
                       Value = m["name"].ToString())
                   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Im getting a parameter error using this, i think its because the response is essentially a list of ienumerable<jtokens>

Comment: What is the return type of `Children()`?

Comment: Probably the mistake is that m["name"] is not a string. Try .ToString() or cast it. I updated it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
return response["holder"].Children()
               .Select(m => m.FirstCharToUpper())
               .OrderBy(m => m["name"].ToString())
               .Select(m => new SelectedListItem{
                   Text = m["name"].ToString(),
                   Value = m["name"].ToString()
               })
               .ToList();

static class Utility
{
    public static string FirstCharToUpper(this string s)
    {
        return s.First().ToString().ToUpper() + string.Join("", s.Skip(1));
    }
}
```